# try with resources closing the resources unexpectedly

Tags: java

I am trying to invoke the following method inside a while loop. First time, it invokes fine but on 2nd loop execution, it throws an IOException

```
public String getInputString(String prompt){
        System.out.print(prompt);
        String inputLine = null;

        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))){
            inputLine = br.readLine();
            if(inputLine.length() == 0){
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return inputLine;
    }
```

I am getting this IOException:

```
 java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
    at ch5.GameHelper.getInputString(GameHelper.java:14)
    at ch5.SimpleDotComTestDrive.main(SimpleDotComTestDrive.java:19)
```

On the other hand, it is working fine when i try to execute it as follows:

```
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            inputLine = br.readLine();
            if(inputLine.length() == 0){
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

What is the reason for such a behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're calling `getInputString` more than once.

The first time, it should work fine - but then you're closing `System.in` (by closing the `BufferedReader` wrapping `InputStreamReader` wrapping `System.in`)... which means the *next* time you try to read from `System.in`, you won't be able to.

If you remove the try-with-resources statement, you could still have problems, because you'll be creating multiple readers around the same stream - if one of those reads more input than you actually use, it won't be available later on.

I suggest you create a `BufferedReader` wrapping an `InputStreamReader` wrapping `System.in` *once*, at the start of your program, and use that `BufferedReader` instance everywhere.

Comment: Thankyou :) May i ask if there is any way to reset System.in in our program? Or any other alternative to close the BufferedReader connected to System.in (indirectly), instead of making the BufferedReader instance eligible for garbage collection?

Comment: @JeeshuMittal: Garbage collection is entirely separate to closing the stream - it's not like try-with-resources forces an object to be garbage collected. I would suggest you capture a `BufferedReader` for the input *once* at the start of the program, and don't close it - even creating multiple readers around the same stream has potential for problems.